# reshaping of multidimension list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list with shape `(50, 100, 20, 20)`, and I reshape it as follows

```
x = np.array(cells)
train = x[:,:70].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (3500,400)
test = x[:,70:100].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (1500,400)
```

I am new to python and numpy, I want to know how my numpy array with shape  `(50, 100, 20, 20)` 
changes to `(3500,400)` and `(1500,400)` respectively

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape ? (or `help(reshape)` in a python console)

Comment: Yes I have looked at it but was not able to understand, if you know the how it is working then please answer

Comment: Someone's already posted an answer that explains it quite well, so I won't duplicate that.  In the future if you can include which documentation you've looked at and what parts of it you don't understand that will make it much easier to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `x` is a 4-dimensional array.

The indexing operations

- **step-1** `x[:,:70]` produces an array of shape (50, 70, 20, 20)
- **step-2** `x[:,70:100]` produces an array of shape (50, 30, 20, 20)

Then the `.reshape(-1,400)` re-organises the 4-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array in such a way that the final array will have 400 columns(no matter how may rows will be created).

Now, number of elements in **step-1** is 1400000 (`50*70*20*20`) and in **step-2** is 600000 (`50*30*20*20`) respectively.

So, when you squeeze 1400000 elements into 400 columns, you'll get 3500 rows.
Similarly, when you squeeze 600000 elements into 400 columns, you'll get 1500 rows.

Hope this helps!